# Filled Polygons using ggplot in R not working

Tags: r, ggplot2

The following code works well for drawing polygons

```
SP <- SpatialPolygons(spd)
centroids  <- coordinates(SP)
x  <- centroids[,1]
y  <- centroids[,2]
SP1  <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(SP, data = data.frame(x = x, y = y, z = z, row.names = row.names(SP)))
ggplot(data = SP1, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) + geom_path()
```

Instead if I change the last two lines of the code to fill these polygons based on some value vector it does not work:

```
penetration <- runif(n = length(SP), min = 1, max = 10)
SP1  <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(SP, data = data.frame(x = x, y = y, z = z,  value = penetration, row.names = row.names(SP)))
ggplot(data = SP1, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)) + geom_polygon(aes(fill=SP1$value))
```

spd is created with data from the following link:

data source: https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?mid=1mf9TQY3bocarO4SaIXAtco_C1LE&hl=en_US

I then extracted coordinates from the kml file... which is then into a list of Polygons so that I could draw it using some plotting function...

```
tkml <- getKMLcoordinates(kmlfile="Pune all Electoral Wards.kml", ignoreAltitude=T)
len <-length(tkml)

del <- NA
for(i in 1:len)
{
  if(length(tkml[[i]]) == 2)
    del <- c(del, i)
}
del <- del[-1]
tkmlCleaned <- tkml[!tkml %in% tkml[del]]
size <- length(tkmlCleaned)
sr <- vector(mode = "list", length = size)
srs <- vector(mode = "list", length = size)
spd <- list()
for(j in 1:length(sr))
{

  sr[[j]] <- Polygon(tkmlCleaned[[j]])
  srs[[j]] <- Polygons(list(sr[[j]]), j)
  spd <- c(srs[[j]], spd)
}
```

Comment: What is `spd` ?  Can you add a data set to make this reproducible ?

Comment: since I am not used to post in stack overflow, please do not mind mistakes in formatting

Comment: It is best tor provide data using `dput`.  So to get `spd` you would do the following `dput(spd)`

Comment: Thanks for the input. I will share data in some time

Comment: I hope it is fine now, you should be able to run the code directly. 

Regards,
Aditya

Answer (score 0):

I found that the way I had merged polygon fill data with Polygon data is not compatible the data format for ggplot. So the following code did not work

```
SP1  <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(SP, data = data.frame(x = x, y = y, z = z,  value = penetration, row.names = row.names(SP)))
```

First we need to use the fortify command from ggplot2 library

```
SP1  <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(SP, data = data.frame(x = x, y = y, z = z, row.names = row.names(SP)))
abc <- fortify(SP1)
```

[SP1 data snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdnRn.jpg)[abc data snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2u5iq.jpg)

note how data gets stacked upon application of fortify command into lat, long, id, group etc columns.

The id column comes from the Polygons command, where each Polygon is assigned an id as shown in the following code. The second argument in the Polygons function is for the id

```
for(j in 1:length(sr))
{

  sr[[j]] <- Polygon(tkmlCleaned[[j]])
  srs[[j]] <- Polygons(list(sr[[j]]), j)
  spd <- c(srs[[j]], spd)
}
```

To join data in a way which is readable by ggplot I used the function inner_join from dplyr library.
Please note that dplyr package is not available for R 3.1.0, I updated to the latest version.

```
cde <- inner_join(abc, wardDensity1, by = "id")
```

penetration is mapped against id through merging when we use the inner_join function and the result is readable by ggplot

wardDensity contains id (which in this case is electoral ward Name) and population of that ward

```
baseHeatMap <- ggplot(data = cde, aes(long , lat, group = group, fill = penetration)) + geom_polygon(color = "black")
```